# c# threading and a foreach loop

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a high number of records I need to loop through 
For rough numbers lets say 100,000 records

As I loop through these record I need to do some string manipulations and save that string to a text file.  No data is shared between each record, they are independent records of data.

I am thinking I can get through this task quicker by using multiple threads?
If so how I would go about this (with code example)?

I am thinking I don't want an infinite number of threads running at the same time so is there way to kick off a limited number of threads (say 10 threads at a time) and when 1 finishes start another until all 100,000 are complete?

Comment: If you google it "it will come" :)

Comment: I have done that already, threading is new to me so Google is not helping.  Not even sure I am searching for the right thing yet.

Comment: Is there only one output file?  If so, you will need to synchronize access to it, which renders the threading kind of pointless--unless your process is CPU bound, which it probably isn't.  Most likely the biggest bottleneck will be the I/O to the output file, and you should just leave the code as it is.

Comment: Try bing - http://www.bing.com/search?q=c%23+threading+and+a+foreach+loop - which gives you http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460720%28v=vs.110%29.aspx ... Now as @adv12 pointed out you likely not going to benefit from it...

Comment: No, there are individual output files for each record

Comment: In that case, Jonathan Sullinger's answer is looking pretty good...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using .Net 4 or newer you can use the Parallel Task Library. Just include a using statement for LINQ

```
using System.Linq;
using System.IO;
```

Then use the parallel for each.

```
Parallel.ForEach(this.CollectionOfStrings, str => 
{
    // Append to file, or write to a new file if you are not appending
    using (StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(somePath, str, ".txt"))) 
    {
        file.WriteLine(str);
    }   
});
```

It will write each line in parallel. If you have 100,000 lines, it won't create 100,000 threads, the library can determine the optimum number of threads to create and spins up what it can.

Comment: +1. Note that if you need share output files (not case for OP) you should ensure proper synchronization to avoid "file already opened" errors.

Comment: +1 although I have some doubts about file synch access

Comment: Dalorzo, this is just intended for unique files per loop as per the OP request. I will update my example to `Write` instead of `Append`.